# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width() while creating bitmap

Tags: java, android, css, bitmap

I'm rotating custom `GoogleMap` markers as per it's bearing.
My marker is a `20x20 PNG` image which looks like below.
[image]

```
float rotation=loc1.bearingTo(loc2);
            Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotation);
            Bitmap original=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dark_arrow_20);
            Bitmap arrowHead=Bitmap.createBitmap(original, 0, 0, 40, 40, matrix, true);
            final BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(arrowHead);
            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat1, lng1)).icon(bitmapDescriptor).title(vehicleName).snippet("Known @ " + timing + "," + strDate11));
            marker.setAnchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
```

It works on mobile like a charm. The output will look like as follows.
[image]

But when I run my app on a high resolution tablet it crashes.
The stacktrace was

```
09-19 11:10:13.736    9079-9079/? E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.realtech.securetracknew, PID: 9079
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:673)
        at com.realtech.securetracknew.MainPage.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.realtech.securetracknew.ab.onClick(Unknown Source)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4466)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18833)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know what causes the error. Anyone please help.

Comment: what is magic value of 40 ?

Comment: `Log.d` the value of  `original.getWidth()`

Comment: it's `09-19 11:31:18.238    4625-4625/? D/my_original_width﹕ 40`

Comment: see [here](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#661), line 666 checks your source Bitmap width: `x + width > source.getWidth()` just use your debugger and check why this condition is met

Comment: do I have to need four different drawables like `mdpi`,`hdpi`,`xhdpi`,`xxhdpi` for different screens?

Comment: no you dont have, did you run the debugger? also is my_original_width﹕== 40 on the tablet? i dont think so...

Comment: `Log.d` the value of `original.getWidth()` - **call it on the device where you have crashes** - it must be < 40

Comment: so you have the answer, see [here](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#661) again

Comment: So what I have to do to get it fixed? Because I don't know what to do.

Comment: it is so simple that you will find the fix by yourself

Comment: OK. Thanks for your kind help my friend.